# RegEx for matching everything except words starting with a plus sign

Tags: regex, replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Sample string:
`+Z XA( 0,1,6,22,26,33,34,35,36,25,24) +DD +I +M >x1 >bdz +A`

Result should be:
`+Z +DD +I +M +A`
or 
`Z DD I M A`

The regex `(\+\w+)` seems to find all tokens, but I don't know how to define the replace pattern. I'd like to remove everything else.

I use Omnis7 but the regex engine is a compiled Delphi library that I used to extend Omnis7. The regex engine is a full implementation of regex. I tried to find the regex with an online regex tool (regex101.com).

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: the regex `(\+\w+)` seems to find all tokens, but I don't know how to define the replace pattern. I'd like to remove everything else.

Comment: what programming language do ypu use to execute the regex replace?

Comment: go [here](https://regex101.com/) for an easy to use regex editor.

Comment: I use Omnis7 but the regex engine is a compiled Delphi library that I used to extend Omnis7. The regex engine is a full implementation of regex. I tried to find the regex with an online regex tool (regex101.com)

Comment: cant you just replace with an empty string?

Comment: Many answers already, one more idea: [replace `[^+]*(\+\w+\s?)?` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/MLpUyM/4) (this only works, if you don't have any other `+` signs in string besides the ones that should be maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

- Find: `(\+\w+\h?)|.`
- Replace: `$1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MLpUyM/7)

Comment: You don't need the quantifiers after the dot.

Comment: @sln: True, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it

Find `(?:(?!\+\w)[\S\s])*\+(\w+)(?:(?!\+\w)[\S\s])*`
Replace `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/MAW3fT/1

Expanded

```
 (?:
      (?! \+ \w )
      [\S\s] 
 )*
 \+ 
 ( \w+ )                       # (1)
 (?:
      (?! \+ \w )
      [\S\s] 
 )*
```

---

While the other answer looks simple it is 2 times slower than this one.

Benchmarks

```
Regex1:   (\+\w+\h?)|.+?
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   49
Elapsed Time:    2.06 s,   2056.43 ms,   2056428 µs
Matches per sec:   1,191,386


Regex2:   (?:(?!\+\w)[\S\s])*\+(\w+)(?:(?!\+\w)[\S\s])*
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   5
Elapsed Time:    1.00 s,   997.28 ms,   997281 µs
Matches per sec:   250,681
```

What to notice is they both matched correctly, so the elapsed time
is the bell weather here. Where my regex took half the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to settle on a potential pattern but saw that you have already found your answer. Here's a suggestion nevertheless.

Find: `(?<![+\w])[^+][\w\W]+?\s`

Replace: `''`

https://regex101.com/r/cXceQO/1/

Comment: `[+\w+]` matches 1 `+` or 1 `\w`, the second `+` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all here.
I played around with it and found the exact solution:
Search: `+Z XA( 0,1,6,22,26,33,34,35,36,25,24) +DD +I +M >x1 >bdz +A`
Find: `(\+)(\w+\h?)(.?)|.`

1. Replace: `$1$2$3`
   Result: `+Z +DD +I +M +A`

or

2. Replace: `$2$3`
   Result: `Z DD I M A`